# module.exports not working ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the tutorial found here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/blob/master/lessons/14-whats-next/modules/routes.js

However when copying:

```
module.exports = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
      <Route path="/repos/:userName/:repoName" component={Repo}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Route>
)
```

Webstorm is highlighting the brackets and using:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'
```

But **routes** throws the error

```
Default export is not declared in imported module
```

The page just loads blank with no react code. Why can I not export the module as shown in the tutorial code?

The rest of my code is ES6

Comment: Show your package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rselvaganesh is technically correct, however in this case it should be:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
      <Route path="/repos/:userName/:repoName" component={Repo}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Route>
)
```

with no name - which is what was confusing me

Answer (score 2):

This issue was posted [here](https://github.com/darul75/web-react/issues/14)

Changing in AppActions

```
module.exports = alt.createActions(AppActions);
```

To:

```
export default alt.createActions(AppActions);
```

Makes WebStorm happier and doesn't seem to break anything.